# Possible to save and list queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, list, report

I have a database and have saved the code on a separate document for a number of queries - is there anyway of saving them as part of the database as some kind of list so that they can be clicked on to run them rather than keeping on having to paste the code in?

I realise that there are various Reports systems available to purchase on line, but this is a small database and a one-off, and they look complicated and not worth the trouble.

Is there anyway of streamlining this?

Comment: You mean like a 'view'? Obviously, they can't be 'clicked' because the database has no built-in GUI

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can write those sql queries to a script-or bunch of script files- file and directly run on mysql without copy/paste.

```
 mysql -u user -ppass < script.sql
```